# How substr_count(), array_count_values() & count() works internally in PHP? How does it handles performance & speed issue in the case of large data?

Tags: php, arrays, string, performance

I am trying to understand how these functions work internally & how they handle performance & speed issue in large data case. I know they are written in C but I want to understand it & know what can I do when asked & faced with such situations in php. I have also seen its C code on github like [substr_count](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5eb1f92f31cafc48384f9096012f421b37f6d425/ext/standard/string.c#L5580) but can anyone explain me.

Answer (score 3):

These implementions are really straight forward.

**count**

```
// count($a)
it works like `return a.length` in other languages.
```

**array_count_values**

```
// array_count_values(a)
// https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/683123fa39114692b712b8c88d5b2fec9b1fc7ea/ext/standard/array.c
// it works like this:
$r = [];
for($a as $v) {
    $r[$v]++;
}
return $r;
```

**substr_count**

```
// substr_count(p, needle)
if (needle_len == 1) {
    //if there is only one char in needle, just search it in the memory, more effective
    cmp = needle[0];
    while ((p = memchr(p, cmp, endp - p))) {
        count++;
        p++;
    }
} else {
    // just like C's strstr to search
    while ((p = (char*)php_memnstr(p, needle, needle_len, endp))) {
        p += needle_len;
        count++;
    }
}

//or PHP-like version 
//remember: the strchr is strstr in PHP while they are different in C
//so just a demo here
$c = 0;
while($p = strstr($p, $needle)) {
    // get the remaining string
    // in C here is a pointer operation and much more faster
    $p = substr($p, strlen($needle)); 
    $c++;
}
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?